# Быстрый Resize Bitmap C#

Tags: c#, производительность, bitmap, resize, zoom

камрады!

Суть проблемы: нужно в интерактивном режиме ресайзить Bitmap порядка 3*4 тыщи пикселей или даже больше. Грубо говоря, зум.

Пробовал:

```
scaled = new Bitmap(baseImage, newSize);
```

Второй вариант:

```
Bitmap scaled = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)scaled))
{
  g.DrawImage(baseImage, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
}
return scaled;
```

И разные вариации, но толку чуть меньше чем ноль.
Единственное, что даёт прирост производительности - подключить OpenCV и использовать их ресайз, но таскать за собой такой хвост - идея не лучшая.

Возможно есть существующие библиотеки как на чистом C# или обёртки (у меня WinForms .net 3.5 проект) полегче того же OpenCV... ТОП Nugeta - обёртки над тем же new Bitmap и результата не дают. Или я плохо искал. В общем, я открыт для предложений.

**UPD: информация к размышлению. У меня уже черепушка плавится.**

Запускаю вот такой код с отрисовкой получившегося изображения прямо на контрол. Всё летает.

```
//прицеплено на Form1.paint
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
var g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawImage(baseImage, new RectangleF(0, 0, baseImage.Width * Scale, baseImage.Height * Scale));
}
```

Но! Если получать Graphics объект не из PaintEventArgs, а из Graphics.FromImage(baseImage), то скорость работы строчки

```
g.DrawImage(baseImage, new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height));
```

разнится в разы.
Вот это-то и смущает. Мне нужно не просто отрисовать изображение на контрол, а отрисовать его именно в конкретный объект. 
То есть, код:

```
scaledImage.Dispose();
scaledImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
var g = Graphics.FromImage(scaledImage);
g.DrawImage(baseImage, new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height));
```

Работает примерно в 10-12 раз медленнее кода:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   var g = e.Graphics;
   g.DrawImage(baseImage, new RectangleF(0, 0, baseImage.Width * Scale, baseImage.Height * Scale));
   pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Здесь идёт отрисовка на контрол сразу и выполняется это почти моментально. Но мне нужно записать всё в Bitmap объект.

Самое забавное, что если перейти внутрь g.DrawImage(), то в обоих случаях вызывается один и тот же метод DrawImage из System.Drawing, но при одном объекте Graphics он летает, а при том, что мне нужно - полученном через Graphics.FromImage() - тормозит

Comment: Битмап один и тот же иcпользуется много раз? (например - карта, один раз загрузили, посмотрели в разном масштабе, разные части)

Comment: @MBo, сейчас да, в base хранится исходник и в зависимости от зума он копируется в scaled каждый раз с новыми шириной и высотой. Scaled - один и тот же объект тоже

Comment: я когда то юзал https://leafletjs.com/, [демо](https://rawgit.com/tym32167/LeafletMapSample/master/index.html), [исходники](https://github.com/tym32167/LeafletMapSample)

Comment: В медленном коде действительно каждый раз пересоздаётся битмап scaledImage??

Comment: Хм... Получается, что да. И каждый раз он должен быть присвоен одному и тому же объекту, связанному с контролом

Comment: Сама задача. Кастомный контрол на основе панели. Писалось в дикой древности под  3.5 с прицелом на все системы начиная от XP. На заднем фоне наша растровая картинка как подложка. На ней юзер рисует свои краказябры - геометрические примитивы. Соответственно по колесику параллельно масштабируется и наш фон и вся мазня юзера - оно правда всё векторное и пересчитывается отдельно. И на зуме за 100-200 процентов начинется жесть. Использование свойства backgroundimage не спасает ибо картинка может занимать только часть фона.

Comment: scaledImage пересоздавайте только тогда, когда без этого не обойтись - например, при ресайзе формы надо? Или при изменении масштаба?

Comment: При каждом скролле мышкой если я правильно понял что вы имеете в виду. И при ресайзе формы тоже

Comment: Любопытно. Я было подумал, что дело в PixelFormat. Но даже если его задать у scaledImage таким же, как у baseImage, ничего не меняется. Также проверил все свойства графиксов: из события Paint и полученного из изображения - все они одинаковые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть выгодно разбить битмап на прямоугольные части.

Изображение такого размера ведь в большинстве случаев целиком не показывают, а масштабирование одной или, скажем, четырёх из 16 частей явно быстрее, чем всего большого битмапа.

Кроме того, можно предрассчитать - или заранее, или в начале работы программы - несколько копий в других масштабах.

Для показа целой картинки на стандартных мониторах отображаем готовую копию с масштабом 0.5 или 0.25. Если масштаб промежуточный - можно из тех же уменьшенных сделать.

Для увеличенного масштаба нарезанные куски хорошо подойдут.

Comment: Вот только как узнать какая часть изображения сейчас активна чтобы масштабировать именно её?

Comment: Так должны быть известны координаты выводимого прямоугольника

Answer (score 0):

Может, я что-то упустил, но почему-бы не использовать функционал доступный из коробки?

Ты используешь Winforms. У него есть PictureBox. У него есть режим Zoom. Просто меняешь скролом размер этого PictureBox и получаешь зум. Перемещение по картинке -- реализуй перетягивание PictureBox внутри некой панели по клику.

Ни тормозов не должно быть ни излишних ресайзов оригинального битмапа.